Schedule a report to account owners
I have a Account report which needs to sent to all account owners. If any user who don't own accounts should not receive the report.
Any thoughts on how we can achieve this?
I initially thought of having all account owners in a group, but that wouldn't work if somebody no longer owns accounts but still is in the Group.
I am pretty much sure there is no out of the box solution. But if there is any I am all ears for it.
Another option I can think of is use a scheduled flow to add/remove users(account Owners) from group just before the scheduled report is run.
Any other better option?
Update:
I am planning to use Report subscriptions and one single report to all users

this needs more information -- are you sending separate reports, one per owner? or are you sending one report to only owners of Accounts?  Are you using Report subscriptions for this? Please use [edit]

I currently i am using one single report to all. Yes plan to use report subscriptions

related Q&A. - you're looking for dynamic Group membership.  I can see no way of doing this besides the scheduled precursor job to collect all the account owners at that moment and then rebuild the Public Group members

https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdWJ4UAN/include-record-owners-as-recipient-option-when-scheduling-reports
